# I broke the Gnome Settings –> Background

Tags: gnome, system-settings, desktop-background

I was working toward creating a new background image slideshow. I created a new XML pair for the settings and for the slideshow. My proof-of-concept files worked (two images and transitions moving back and forth once the new slideshow was selected from Settings).

This PoC used symlinks in a single folder. My next step was t o test two images from directly within the folder hierarchy. These file paths may contain special characters. I selected two files where one merely included spaces and a second which included three special characters (the ’ and the open and closed squares: []).

The file with the spaces worked as expected; the other did not display in the slideshow. I then added quotations around the paths to see if this would remedy the matter. It did not.

However, this testing broke the background settings. I suspect whatever ingests those XML files now contains corrupted data and can no longer do its job. That’s just a guess.

What do I mean by broken? There are no longer any images or slideshow objects listed in the settings one might select. The newly created was present until I removed those files. The default (two slideshows and a handful of images) are all gone from the settings dialog (though all remain in the file system as expected).

Once I removed my new slideshow (both XML files) and chose a different file as a background (using the still functional Add Picture button), that new slideshow also vanished from the background settings.

Reboots have not helped and this (of course) impacts all users.

How can I fix this? What did that ingested XML break?

Ubuntu 22.04

Also asked on Gnome:  https://discourse.gnome.org/t/i-broke-the-gnome-settings-background/14420

Comment: Does no one have any idea what application manages this background changing?

Comment: from which folder did you delete the xml? Have you tried reinstalling the gnome-settings? This might invoke some hooks re-adding the default xml entries. I would be very surprised if the ingested xml broke "something", I find it more likely that you accidentally removed a default entry.

Comment: What default entry would that be?  There are two files which control the (any) default slideshow.  Those are the only two files impacted and they have been returned to the default location.  Keep in mind this is impacting any and all users, including any new user I might create.  This is more than just my user's two files (or any other files that could happen to live in my folder).